# Viewpager not visible when inflating the view above it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

I've been stuck on this for hours and I can't figure out what's causing this issue.
I have an activity that uses a fragment called "UserActivityFragment". The fragment view is divided into 2 main layouts, "profile_container" and "viewpager". ViewPager is below the profile_container layout and contains 3 fragments. "profile_container" layout is inflated by another fragment called "profileFragment". Now the issue is that if I inflate "profile_container" layout, the viewpager disappears and I see nothing below "profile_container". I'm not sure why this is happening because I'm using the same layout and fragment code in another activity of my application. "profile_container" takes half the screen size to display it's view, so it's not a height issue with viewpager. I'm not sure what's causing this to happen.

Here's what the "UserProfileFragment" looks like:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.UserProfile, container, false);


        viewpager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.profileviewpager);

        tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.profiletabs);

        profileview = new profileFragment();
        profileview.Arguments = user;
        var trans = Activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.profile_container, profileview, "userProfile");

        trans.Commit();


        var adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(Activity, ChildFragmentManager);
        adapter.addFrag(new ProfileFeed(), "posts", user);
        adapter.addFrag(new followingFragment(), "following", user);
        adapter.addFrag(new FollowFragment(), "followers", user);
        viewpager.Adapter = adapter;

        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewpager);

        tabLayout.GetTabAt(0).SetText("Posts");

        tabLayout.GetTabAt(1).SetText("Followings");

        tabLayout.GetTabAt(2).SetText("Followers");

        return view;
    }
}
```

and here's the layout inflated by "UserProfileFragment"

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+id/profileviewpager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
  android:id="@+id/appbar">
<FrameLayout
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    android:id="@+id/profilecontainerFrameLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
      android:id="@+id/profile_container"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_tabs_height"
  app:tabMode="fixed"
  app:tabGravity="center"
  style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
  android:id="@+id/profiletabs" />
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for the viewpager not showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of your view pager to `match_parent`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I changed height to "match_parent" but the viewpager still doesn't show.